# Transferring one fragment among two frameLayouts in one activity programmatically

Tags: android, transactions, fragment

In my app (when in landscape) there are two frameLayouts one left, and one right inside the same Activity.

In left hand side is a listView (menu) and in right hand side should display listView ("table") or form fragment.

Now, if an item is selected from the "table" in the right hand side frameLayout, that "table" fragment should be transferred into left hand side frameLayout, and instead of that "table" fragment, now comes a new one.

So, my question is how to transfer programmatically one fragment from one frameLayout to another frameLayout in the same activity?

Basically the problem is how to transfer one fragment from one View to another View inside one activity.

I've tried to remove/replace with fragment transaction, but couldn't do it because the fragment from the right hand side frameLayout has the ID of that frameLayout, which is different from the right hand side frameLayout.

The flow of the app should be like switching and replacing all other fragments from one frameLayout to another in the described manner.

So, if someone knows how to do it, I would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after hours, and hours of testing, I came up with this solution for a problem of shifting/moving fragment from one container to another. This is the case with two `FrameLayout` views.

```
//First create New fragment which should replace the one in the RIGHT FrameLayout
MyFragmentForRightFrameLayout myFragmentForRightFrameLayout = new MyFragmentForRightFrameLayout;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Set whatever arguments to a Bundle
bundle.set.... ;
//Find last fragment on BackStack, or find it by ID of the container in which the FragmentToMove resides, and get it so you can get its Bundle arguments  
Fragment fragmentToMove = fragManager.findFragmentByTag(fragManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName());
//Instantiate the same type of fragment as the one you want to remove
YourFragment fragmentToAdd = new YourFragment();
//Set arguments to a new Fragment FROM the fragment you found on a backstack    
fragmentToAdd.setArguments(fragmentToMove.getArguments());
fragmentTransacion = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//Replace the fragment in right FrameLayout with new fragment (whichever type)
fragTransaction.replace(frameLayoutRight.getId(), myFragmentForRightFrameLayout, "Tag for this Fragment");
//And finaly replace the left FrameLayout fragment with the newly created fragment of the same type as the one you wish to move to the left FrameLayout
fragTransaction.replace(frameLayoutLeft.getId(), fragmentToAdd, "Tag for this fragment");
fragTransaction.addToBackStack("Tag for transaction" or null);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Ok, so the problem was that when you try to MOVE a fragment from one container (in my case FrameLayout), to another container, you CAN NOT do this directly by finding a fragment and simply replacing it because it has an ID of the RIGHT FrameLayout, which the fragment got when it was added to a RIGHT FrameLayout. It is impossible to remove fragment's ID, nor you can set new one.

So, you need to make a new fragment of the same type, which HAS NO ID, and set into it a bundle from the fragment you are removing/replacing.

The MAIN problem with the solution that @Ekundayo Blessing Funminiyi gave is that it is not possible to go back to the state you were previously. So this solution makes it possible to navigate back to a previous screens (fragment combinations).

And, that's it. Happy coding. I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Nice. Glad you have finally found a working solution. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Define an `interface` inside your "table" fragment, the interface should look like this:

```
public interface FragmentReplacerListerner{

    void replace();

}
```

implement this interface inside your Activity.

Now, in the onAttach() method of "table" fragment , cast your activity as a replacer. Call the `replace()` method on the listener in "table" fragment when it needs to be replaced.

implement the callback like this in your activity

```
void replace(){
   //replace your left FrameLayout with right fragment
   // inflate the right FrameLayout with new Fragment
}
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/blessochampion/FragmentSwitcher) to the implementation of a sample app

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried your solution, and it doesn't work, and I get the same error, as before:

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment TableFragmentNew{cfdfb17 #2 id=0x3ea}: was 1002 now 1001"

Problem is that the fragment gets the ID of the frameLayout inside which it was before, and if I try to put it in a "left hand side frameLayout" which has a different ID it throws exception...

Comment: You need to first remove it from the right FrameLayout before you add it to the left FrameLayout.

Comment: Please see below my implementation of the method replace(), and if you could comment it.. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks for your example. I've tried the example, and it works what it says, BUT, I forgot to mention... I need the transactions put to backstack, because, when a user press back (in the toolBar/actionBar), transactions must reverse. Another problem is that when I have table "in the left", after selecting several records from the table, when pressed back, it needs to go back to "main menu - table" state, not to go back through all the previously opened records. It's a tricky app flow...

Comment: So the flow in the LANDSCAPE is as follows:
1. Left - Main menu, Right - empty
2. (Something from the menu is selected) - Left - Main menu, Right table or form.
3. (If a record is selected from the table) - Left table, Right form with the record details.
4. (If another record is selected from the table) - Left table, Right form with the record details.
5. (If back is pressed) - Left Main menu, Right table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what's in replace method:

```
@Override
public void replace() {
    TableFragmentNew tableFragmentNew = (TableFragmentNew)fragManager.findFragmentById(frameLayoutLand.getId());
    fragTransaction.remove(tableFragmentNew).commit();
    fragManager.executePendingTransactions();
    fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.add(frameLayout.getId(), tableFragmentNew);
    fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

Is it ok like that?

Comment: I will write a sample code for you during my lunch today. Hopefully, it won't be too late by then.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I'm implementing totally different approach with simply adding and removing fragments inside one container. But I would like to see the solution with two different FrameLayouts in one activity.

Comment: No problem...I will do that.